# Preventing auto lock on Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When the user installs the application for the first time on Windows Mobile, I am creating some encryption keys to do the authentication of the application with some webservices.

The problem that I have is that the phone is autolocking and the task is canceled. I am not able to prevent it from closing.

I have used this in the mainpage.xaml load:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

and even in the App.xaml:

```
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
    }
```

but still it is not working.  Any help, please, the task is taking about 2 min.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `ApplicationIdleDetectionMode`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.applicationidledetectionmode(v=vs.105).aspx.

Comment: Agree. That's the way to go. VS2012 has this setting on its WP8 template.